# Android Lollipop Toolbar vs Custom view

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-toolbar

I just read about the new Toolbar in Android Lollipop.
It inherits from ViewGroup.

Why are the advantages of using the new Toolbar over, say, a LinearLayout
to place your own views?

Comment: its already built and you dont have to reinvent the wheel. If you need something specific then by all means use your own custom method to display what you want

Comment: Was there anything else you needed help with?

Comment: No, I understand now why the Toolbar was made this way and how it can be reused for various design patterns! Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### Explanation:

You should start using a `ToolBar` instead of the `ActionBar`. This is directly taken from the Android Developer documentation. It allows more flexibility than the normal `ActionBar`; however, retains some the more prominent features such as adding a **Logo**, supports **"up" Navigation**, **inflating menus** and **actionviews** such as the SearchView.

### Tutorials:

[Implement yourself(by Chris Banes)](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/)

[Collapsing Toolbar, `FloatingActionButton`, `NavigationView`, `Snackbar`(by Chris Banes)](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare)

### Documentation:

[Normal `Toolbar`(API 21+)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

[AppCompat Support v7 `Toolbar`(API 7+)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html)

> A standard toolbar for use within application content.
>
> A **Toolbar** is a generalization of action bars for use within
>   application layouts. While an action bar is traditionally part of an
>   Activity's opaque window decor controlled by the framework, a Toolbar
>   may be placed at any arbitrary level of nesting within a view
>   hierarchy. An application may choose to designate a Toolbar as the
>   action bar for an Activity using the setActionBar() method.
>
> Toolbar supports a more focused feature set than ActionBar. From start
>   to end, a toolbar may contain a combination of the following optional
>   elements:
>
> **A navigation button.** This may be an Up arrow, navigation menu toggle,
>   close, collapse, done or another glyph of the app's choosing. This
>   button should always be used to access other navigational destinations
>   within the container of the Toolbar and its signified content or
>   otherwise leave the current context signified by the Toolbar.
>
> **A branded logo image.** This may extend to the height of the bar and can
>   be arbitrarily wide.
>
> **A title and subtitle.** The title should be a
>   signpost for the Toolbar's current position in the navigation
>   hierarchy and the content contained there. The subtitle, if present
>   should indicate any extended information about the current content. If
>   an app uses a logo image it should strongly consider omitting a title
>   and subtitle.
>
> **One or more custom views.** The application may add
>   arbitrary child views to the Toolbar. They will appear at this
>   position within the layout. If a child view's Toolbar.LayoutParams
>   indicates a Gravity value of CENTER_HORIZONTAL the view will attempt
>   to center within the available space remaining in the Toolbar after
>   all other elements have been measured.
>
> **An action menu.** The menu of
>   actions will pin to the end of the Toolbar offering a few frequent,
>   important or typical actions along with an optional overflow menu for
>   additional actions. In modern Android UIs developers should lean more
>   on a visually distinct color scheme for toolbars than on their
>   application icon. The use of application icon plus title as a standard
>   layout is discouraged on API 21 devices and newer.