# Set text for a TextView in a layout coming from LayoutInflator

Tags: android

I'm making a custom action bar layout, and I want to reuse it in all activities. For that I want to be able to set the title in the action bar layout to the activity title,

```
View actionBarView =LayoutInflater.from(senderActivity.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.az_actionbar, null);
((TextView)actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.azActionBar_tv_title)).setText("tetetete");
```

But the TextView doesn't change its text (doesn't show "tetetetete")

Any ideas why is this happening? or is there a better way to apply the custom ActionBar layout globally?
[The method I used to customize the actionbar.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18418689/1894630)

Java code of the helper method that is being called on onCreate from each activity with `Helper.setAzCustomActionBar(this)`:

```
public static void setAzCustomActionBar(AppCompatActivity sender){

    //getting the activity title
    String title;
    try {
        ActivityInfo activityInfo = sender.getPackageManager().getActivityInfo(
                sender.getComponentName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        title = activityInfo.loadLabel(sender.getPackageManager())
                .toString();
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        title = "abcd";
    }


    View actionBarView = LayoutInflater.from(sender.getApplicationContext()).inflate(R.layout.az_actionbar, null);
    //This is the line that doesn't work
    ((TextView) actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.azActionBar_tv_title)).setText(title);
    sender.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    sender.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.az_actionbar);
}
```

Comment: Go ahead and add the code for the action bar. I can't figure out what's going on with only what you posted.

Comment: Also, if you want a custom action bar you should try the new Toolbar API from the support library. It will allow you more customizations further along the way.

Comment: Do you mean the Layout XML code, or the function of customizing the action bar?

Comment: Let's start with the Java code first.

Comment: I intended to do so, but not in this project as I'm already late :)

Comment: Never too late to update to Toolbar. I just updated a huge project with 3 modules/apps in 2 days.

Comment: yup. Toolbar is the way to go now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the "changed" custom view as a custom view for the action bar.

Change `sender.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.az_actionbar);` to `sender.getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(actionBarView);`

Answer (score 0):

"or is there a better way to apply the custom ActionBar layout globally?"

Yes. The best way is to use the Toolbar widget.

```
android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="#2196F3"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This answer talks about it - [Android Lollipop Toolbar vs Custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508934/android-lollipop-toolbar-vs-custom-view)

https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/

http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

https://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/